# Arcpy 2.7 - Update file geodatabe field formatting question

Tags: python-2.7, arcgis

I am trying to figure out how to format a text variable grabbed from a file geodatabase table and update another file geodatabase table field with this variable. The fields in both tables are text fields with a field size 300. The entire column is to be updated with the same value extracted from table1. I cannot seem to format var1 in the arcpy.CalculateField_management statement correctly.

A separate table is created for each row searched and an sql query built from values in row[2]. Using the sql, records are selected from a third table and saved with the file name grabbed from row[0]. Once the records are saved to this table, I add a new field and update it with the value from row[1]. All this is done correctly up to when I try to update the "Description" field. I am pretty sure it is a formatting issue.

---

the value from table1 grabbed via SearchCursor:

```
var = row[1]
```

I want to update the field "Description" in table2. I have tried the following formats:

```
var1  = var
var1 = '!' + var + '!'
arcpy.CalculateField_management("table2", "Description", var1, "PYTHON3")

var1 = '"' + var + '"'
arcpy.CalculateField_management("table2", "Description", var1, "PYTHON3")
arcpy.CalculateField_management("table2", "Description", "'" + var1 + "'", "PYTHON3")
```

I am stumped. I am at home and the code is a work which is why I did not include it. I think this enough to go by though. Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Using ArcMap 10.6.1

Comment: I feel like you're overthinking this - is it not just `arcpy.CalculateField_management("table2", "Description", var)` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll assume from the quotes you are throwing around var contains a string.  In which case you want :

```
arcpy.CalculateField_management("table2", "Description", "'" + var + "'", "PYTHON3")
```

Note that I used 'var' not 'var1'.  If var contains a number you can simply do:

```
arcpy.CalculateField_management("table2", "Description", var, "PYTHON3")
```

Comment: It turns out the field lengths were not the same and the number of characters in the description field was one character too long. Sometimes stepping back and coming at it another day really helps. Thanks Anna.